# Avoiding code duplication in django settings files

Tags: python, django, settings, django-settings, 12factor

I am following Django settings best practices by using `base.py`, `local.py`, `prod.py`, and `staging.py`.

My conundrum is whether or not to be okay with code duplication. Let's take this example. I need to set a URL which is used in a large dictionary of fixed values to configure a package.

`local.py
CONF_URL = 'hard coded local value'`

`prod.py
CONF_URL = os.environ['CONF_URL']`

`staging.py
CONF_URL = 'some other hard coded value'`

I then have code like

```
PACKAGE_CONF = {
  'CONF_URL': CONF_URL,
  'foo1': bar,
  'foo2': bar,
  'foo3': bar,
  'foo4': bar,
  'foo5': bar,
}
```

- I can't put `PACKAGE_CONF` in `base.py` because we import `base` from the leaf settings files and not the other way around.
- I can write something to post process `PACKAGE_CONF` like using an env file but that seems unnecessarily complicated.
- I can force the user to take `CONF_URL` from the environment but that's not a good local dev experience.
- And lastly I can duplicate `PACKAGE_CONF` in `local`, `staging,` and `prod`.

I'm not super pleased with any of these options. Can someone with experience in writing beautiful settings files offer a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *.env* file for setting up the variables of local/dev environment, and ensure you have this same variables set up in staging/prod envs.

*.env* file values will be used only when the environment var is not present. So, you can push the *.env* file to your code repo.

In that way, you will be able to write just once your var in *base.py* file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up doing is this

in `base.py` I put

```
PACKAGE_CONF = {
  'foo1': bar,
  'foo2': bar,
  'foo3': bar,
  'foo4': bar,
  'foo5': bar,
}
```

And then I override `PACKAGE_CONF['CONF_URL']` in the leaf settings files, e.g. in staging.py

```
CONF_URL = 'some other hard coded value'
PACKAGE_CONF['CONF_URL'] = CONF_URL
```

The downside is you might forget to add this value when you create a new leaf settings file and that may lead to unexpected behavior since the dictionary exists but one key is missing.

However, I think this is acceptable since when you create a new leaf settings you usually copy paste an existing one.